# Constructor vs Classes

Tags: javascript, oop

What's the difference between these two, and which is more used, more efficient?

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name
        this.age = age
    }
}
```

OR

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
}
```

Comment: @SureshAtta Did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: I think you'll enjoy this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tllw4EPhLiQ

Comment: Only difference I know of is the second one is hoisted, whereas the first one has to physically be defined first, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Hoisting)

Comment: @phuzi Damn. Thought Java :P